# Conjugacy classes in space of trace zero 2*2 matrices

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-actions, linear-groups

I'm trying to find the orbits when $SL_2$ operates by conjugation on $\mathfrak{sl}_2=Lie(SL_2)=\{A|\operatorname{tr} A=0\}$.

I have tried to write $X\in sl_2$ and corresponding $AXA^{-1}$ for random $A\in SL_2$ in form of $xE_1+yE_2+zE_3$, where $
   E_1=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 0 \\
   0 & -1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$,$
   E_2=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   0 & 1 \\
   0 & 0 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$,$
   E_3=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   0 & 0 \\
   1 & 0 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$, and find that for fixed $x_0$, all $
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   x_0 & y \\
   z & -x_0 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$ where $yz\leq x_0^2$ are in one orbit, but I can`t see how to deal with the rest.

Comment: Note that the orbit of $X$ contains its Jordan form. Since the trace is zero, this would be $\begin{pmatrix}a&1\\0&-a\end{pmatrix}$ or $\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\0&-a\end{pmatrix}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The orbits of $\operatorname{GL}_2$ on $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ are labelled by the Jordan type of the matrices, which (because we are acting on traceless matrices) fall into two families: $\begin{pmatrix}\lambda & 0 \\ 0 & -\lambda\end{pmatrix}$ for any $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$, and also $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. The orbits of $SL_2$ should be the same.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i tried to restrict to real matrices, so non-real λ are imaginary here and orbits with determinants $-λ^2=constant$ will be preserved under restriction.

Comment: @HongruiLi You should point out what field you're working over! In the real case, you get $\begin{pmatrix} \lambda & 0 \\ 0 & -\lambda\end{pmatrix}$ for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, then also $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, then also $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & \mu \\ -\mu & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ for all $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$ which correspond to those purely imaginary eigenvalue matrices.